# Get values from a list that are parameters in a function in R

Tags: r, function-parameter

I have a list and a function, where the list contains values for some of the function parameters

```r
param <- list(
  a = 3
, b = 2
, c = 1
)

foo <- function(a, b, d) a + b + d
```

and I want to call the function with the values from the list. My current approach is

```
foo_param <- param[intersect(names(param), formalArgs(foo))]
foo_param$d <- 4

do.call(foo, foo_param)
```

But this seems long and hard to read. Is there a simpler way of doing this?

---

Yes, I know I can do `foo(param$a, param$b, d=4)`, but this becomes hard to read if there are many arguments and/or the list name is long and repeated.

---

Yes, I know I can rewrite `foo <- function(a, b, d, ...)`, and discard arguments in `...`, but discarding arguments is a nice way to introduce bugs.

---

The situation arised from having a model (defined as a list) with many parameters, and functions accepting only a few of those.

Comment: I think you've already found your solution. I'm not sure how you can really make that any more simple. I mean, you could write it into a helper function to make it cleaner. It probably makes sense to remove your "answer" form your "question" and post it below as a proper answer. If someone else has a better idea, they can post an alternative answer. This doesn't seem like a common enough operation to have a shorter form.